# Should I create different git repository for different AWS lambda functions?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

There are some cons for using single repository for all my lambda functions of a project like:-

- Size of deployment package becomes huge. So, when only 1 lambda is changed, entire package is recreated and deployed to AWS.

Also, different repositories for different lambdas can give us privilege of changing lambda code without affecting other lambdas, but it has its own cons.

So, what is the best design for coding in the AWS lambdas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, I found out.

You need to group relevant lambda functions for e.g 4 lambda functions for CRUD operations corresponding to a single resource should be in a single repository.

Lambda functions concerning with different resource or irrelevant functions should be in a different repository.

Reference: Serverless framework documentation.